# How to create a custom form_tag_helper?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I'm trying to write a form_tag_helper that will allow me to include a `div contenteditable` inside of a rails form. I know that I can customize form_builder by writing a class that inherits from ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder. My problem is that even at this level I still need to return some sort `text_field_tag` or some other type of field_tag. I'm trying to figure out how to write a custom class that inherits from ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper. How can I write such a method so that it returns something along the lines of `<div contenteditable>`?

Comment: I did this a few months back and [this was a great help](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#customizing-form-builders). As well as [this](http://vanderburg.org/Speaking/CustomRailsHelpers.pdf). Let us know how you get on. All the best.